# How can I get GoogleFinance to see the return of a stock from a specified date range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

How can I see the percentage of return from a stock from a specified date range to today? For example: February 19, 2020 to today = -31.93%.

So far I have:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",datevalue(today()-365)),2,2) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

It was:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price") / INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","2/19/2020"),2,2) - 1
```